# How to have separate pages databound?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm wanting to use a datasource to go through records but one at a time per page.

So I'd like a whole page to be dedicated to a single record.

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your scenario?

Comment: I have a datasource of test questions, and I want to display only one question at a time on the screen, with a button for each choice. When a choice is picked the app moves to the next question. and I want to tell the datasource to move back and forwards using buttons on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is just swap out the DataContext on the page.  So don't bind to the list, bind to individual items in list.

```
private List<Question> _questions = new List<Question>();
private int _currentItem = 0;

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _currentItem++;
    this.DataContext = _questions[_currentItem];
}

private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _currentItem--;
    this.DataContext = _questions[_currentItem];
}
```

Now obviously you would have to add bounds checking to make sure you don't go past the last question, or before the first question, but you get the idea.

If you are using MVVM the idea is pretty much the same - you want the viewmodel to model a single item rather than the list of items, then you just swap the data for that current item as you navigate forward or backwards.

Comment: this.DataContext is what i was missing. so then do I just put `{binding QuestionText}` to display that particular property in the list?